# What would be the equivalent foreach loop look like in android

Tags: android

What would be the equivalent foreach loop look like in android java I am porting the below code to android .This for loops is working for c#.

```
        foreach (XmlNode candidate in parent.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (candidate is XmlElement && candidate.Name == element.Name)
            {
                if (candidate == element)
                {
                    return index;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
```

below is my function for android which gets error in the for loop:

```
  private static int FindElementIndex(Element element)
  {
    Node parentNode = element.getParentNode();
    if (parentNode.equals(Node.DOCUMENT_NODE))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    Element parent = (Element)parentNode;
    int index = 1;
    //how should be the foreach of the below to be changed?
    for (Node candidate  : parent.getChildNodes()) {
        if (candidate.equals(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  && candidate.getNodeName() == element.getNodeName())
        {
            if (candidate == element)
            {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
      }

    Log.d("Log_d","Couldn't find element within parent");
    //throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't find element within parent");
}
```

Comment: what do you feel is wrong with your code? is it giving wrong result?

you can try java 8 feature of `parent.getChildNodes().forEach()` I am not sure just try this.

Comment: Please make the objective clear in your question.

Answer (score 1):

// parent.ChilNodes is some type of colleciton like arraylist

some update it show be for not foreach

```
for(XmlNode candidate : parent.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (candidate instanceOf XmlElement && candidate.Name == element.Name)
        {
            if (candidate == element)
            {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is no "foreach" keyword in java.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function and for loop in the function like this

```
 private static int FindElementIndex(Element element)
{
    Node parentNode = element.getParentNode();
    if (parentNode.equals(Node.DOCUMENT_NODE))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    Element parent = (Element)parentNode;
    int index = 1;
    NodeList nodes = parent.getChildNodes();
    for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {
       Node  candidate = nodes.item(k);
        if (candidate.equals(Node.ELEMENT_NODE)  && candidate.getNodeName() == element.getNodeName()) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }

    Log.d("Log_d","Couldn't find element within parent");
    //throw new ArgumentException("Couldn't find element within parent");
    return 0;
}
```